# Outlook: Is there a button/method to "Reply to Some"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

Is there any way to have or create a button/action to "Reply to Some" on emails?

Specifically, I want to Reply to the Sender and include the CC line, but I do **not** want to include the other recipients. Weirdly, this use case is really common in my organization, as we often CC folks for conversation awareness.

While I'm comfortable working in VBA, I'm not able to download any extensions or add-ins.

Comment: no. reply all, and remove the people you want to remove.

Comment: Agree with Frank Thomas, there's no such option in Outlook which meets your requirement.

Comment: Well dang. That's really sad to hear.